# Show element on hover of different element

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to create an interactive map, in which a group of people's locations is shown on the map permanently, and on hover of these location indicators, a table appears giving 4 pieces of information on that particular person.
I've created two elements to represent the location and the information table respectively, and am now trying to make one of these elements appear on hover of the other one.

Please see fiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/8ymdmzv1/

I have browsed the site, and found various methods including changing the opacity with css and showing/hiding with jquery (see below for suggestions found - I have reset the the element styling in the current fiddle) but without joy. Problem seems to be linking the two elements together but after a full afternoon.

```
.dot:hover + .info { opacity: 1 }
.dot:hover > .info { opacity: 1 }
.dot:hover .info { opacity: 1 }

$(".dot").hover(function() {
   $('.info').show();
   }, function(){
$('.info').hide();
});
```

My first real project for fun so would appreciate anyones assistance on getting me past this roadblock.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have:

```
// create info table
var info = document.createElement( 'a' );
info.className = 'info';
holder.appendChild( info );

// create fixed dot
var dot = document.createElement( 'a' );
dot.className = 'dot';
holder.appendChild( dot );
```

So `.info` element goes before `.dot` and `.dot:hover + .info` selector not worknig.
It works, if you can reorder elements to this:

```
// create fixed dot
var dot = document.createElement( 'a' );
dot.className = 'dot';
holder.appendChild( dot );

// create info table
var info = document.createElement( 'a' );
info.className = 'info';
holder.appendChild( info );
```

It is probably better to hide/show elements with `display` property in your case. So, you can do something like this in your css:

```
.info { display: none; } /* Hide .info by default */
.dot:hover + .info { display: block; } /* Show .info, if .dot hovered */
.info:hover { display: block; } /* And stays visible, while .info hovered itself */
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Makes sense. I can get cracking on turning my info elements in tables now!